# Twenty Eleven Theme - SEO Yoast duplicate site titles

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm using a Twenty Eleven Theme with the SEO Yoast Plugin and I have encountered that once the plugin is installed, duplicate site titles appear on my site, like this:

```
<title>Home | beethetravelerbeethetraveler | a life journey</title>
```

I googled and found a fix with editing the header.php and replace everything in between the `<title>…</title>` with the following.

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

My header.php looks like the following: wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

So I'm not sure how to do it. Can somebody point me in the right direction?
Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Nevermind! I found out by myself :)

Comment: Please post your answer so that others can learn too :)

Comment: The fix was to replace EVERYTHING in between the <title>…</title> with this code <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title> and not only the wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); i posted.